Balanced Cantilevel Bridges with FT professional literature
I am A civil Engienner in the Bridge industry.
I am looking for professional books and papers regarding the design of Cast in Place Ballanced Cantilevel Bridges with FT for a job i am invilved in.
I am eager to learn more about this topic and dive into it more comprehensively.
appreciate your answers

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
